# Should manifest.json reference auth.js?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, youtube-api

**Do I need to reference the auth.js in my manifest for this code to work?**

I am building a Google Chrome Extension that will provide a YouTube video in a popup after querying YouTube. To do this with javascript, I am told that I must first set up an auth.js.

I built the auth.js just as mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/javascript).  I made sure to get a project id from the Developer Console.

Here is my ***manifest.json***

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "myOverlay",
  "description": "This extension will create a popout that links to a video specific to the current webpage",
  "version": "1.0",

  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "https://*.youtube.com/",
    "https://*.ytimg.com/"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
   "content_security_policy": 
      "script-src 'self' https://*.youtube.com https://*.ytimg.com; object-src 'self'"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, just reference auth.js from popup.html like normal.

Any files within the extension directory are found automatically, you don't need to tell the manifest about them.